# How to define singleton method in Python

Tags: python, ruby, singleton

In Ruby we have multiple ways that allow us to access and modify the singleton class of the instance, such as
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class
or
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-define_singleton_method

Is there anything similar in Python?
Or what is the most convenient way to reach the same result here?

I've found a few ways of implementing the Singleton pattern in Python. But I'm curious if there's more laconic way

Comment: In Ruby you have the concept of singleton class or eigenclass which holds methods for individual objects (so-called singleton methods). You also have the [`Singleton`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Singleton.html) module which implements the (GoF) singleton pattern. They are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, there isn't a direct equivalent to Ruby's `define_singleton_method` or `singleton_class methods`.

If you're looking to implement the Singleton pattern, where only one instance of a class exists, you can use a metaclass. A metaclass allows you to customize class creation.

```py
class SingletonMeta(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(SingletonMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class SingletonClass(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
    def some_method(self):
        print("Method of a singleton class")

instance1 = SingletonClass()
instance2 = SingletonClass()
print(instance1 is instance2)  # True - both are the same instance
```

But it is my way, maybe there are better ones.